# Bulk loading Picture Marker Symbols into .style for ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, style, ms-access, png

I have close to 1000 PNG files that I want to make Picture Marker Symbols stored in a .style file.  I am very familiar with Microsoft Access, Python and ArcGIS and I know some C# and .NET.  When I look at the symbols in the .style with Access, they are stored as a Long binary data.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get a PNG into the .style file without loading each one individually?

Comment: I have developed VBA code that does this. Unfortunately it does not work for my BMPs (I fear they are too big). You can try it on yours. Did you solve this another way? I don't see a way to attach my MDB/Style file, but happy to send it to you.

Comment: Thank you for the offer.  I ended up simplifying the symbols and making an svg font with Inkscape, then converting it to ttf and installing it on my machine.  It also had the advantage of being faster when symbolizing in ArcMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have a straightforward solution to bulk load images into a style without programming, so I tackled the problem from a different direction.  Font symbols load faster than images so I used this video to help me make a font with Inkscape.

[SVG font with Inkscape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KX-e6sijGE)